# MySQL Prepared Statements using PDO: Update X where X = Y

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

Updating a column and using that same column as WHERE doesn't seem to work.

E.g.,

```
UPDATE Customers
SET Name ='Foo'
WHERE Name ='Bar';
```

Doesn't seem to work but this one works

```
UPDATE Customers
SET Name ='Foo'
WHERE OtherColumn ='Bar';
```

Is this an expected behavior?

**Update:**

I have verified that both will work on normal SQL updates but when using prepared statements like this, doesn't work:

```
UPDATE Customers
SET Name = :Name
WHERE Name = :Name
```

Comment: Both should work...

Comment: there's only mysql here; nothing else. If something doesn't work; check for errors.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I cannot replicate this finding - but then again, I can't see your table definitions.

Comment: *"Is this an expected behavior?"* - If/when it fails/succeeds; yes.

Comment: maybe you have a trigger in that table that's modifying the first update, otehrwise, it should work fine

Comment: please don't use spam tag if there's no code to support the question. If there's something that isn't working; post the relevant code and the schema. Personally, I feel the question's unclear based on this.

Comment: I removed the php/pdo tags. You can add them back in once you've shown relevance for them. Since that made your question automatically unclear.

Comment: WHat's the error you got there? By itself, the answer is NO, that's not the expected behavior.

Comment: @Alfabravo there really is no error message, it just doesn't execute.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have edited and clarified that I am using PDO prepared statements

Comment: @IMB can u show how are you binding and executing?

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing all the relevant code.

If you test on a single sql fiddle like [this one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3553e5/1/0), you can see that it does work as everyone has said on comments. The update will be performed.

So, the answer to your question is NO, that is not the expected behavior unless you are doing something wrong.